# How to print session time remaining in php?

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

I have a program in PHP and I want to print to the screen how much time the user has until their session expires. I want it to update when they reload the page.

For example a simple message like this:

> Your session expires in 60 minutes

...page reload...

> Your session expires in 59 minutes

Also, how do I set the timeout value?

Comment: what kind of session are you refering to? the $_SESSION has a timeout, but this counter is reset at ever page refresh / ajax call

or is it about some loging in of your own?

Comment: Store the time of session start in a cookie and subtract from now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a cookie with the UNIX time and compare with that.

```
setcookie("start", time(), time ()+3600); // saves a cookie with current UNIX time for one hour
```

Read about setcookie here http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php
If you never used it before, be sure to read the begining carefully.

And compare time like:

```
If (isset($_COOKIE["start"]) and $_COOKIE["start"]+3600<time()){
    echo (time()-$_COOKIE["start"])/60 . " minutes left";
}Else{
    Echo "times up";
}
```

Comment: That seems right but when I test, it always prints 'times up' when I reload the page.

Comment: Actually no that works. I just had the cookie set on the same page. Cheers.

Comment: If you set the cookie on the same page just do a  if(isset(cookie)) first to make sure you don't give the user new 60 minutes