# Sessions expire in my shopping cart after a certain time

Tags: php

My cart items are stored in sessions on my website and after a certain amount of time the session seems to expire and the cart is emptied for some reason. How can I find out how much time is left before the session expires and show the user a timer on the cart page?

Comment: This might be a dupe of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759153/how-to-print-session-time-remaining-in-php

Comment: Is this a hand coded shopping cart or something off the shelf?

Comment: I wrote the code

Comment: In your `php.ini` file you can set the `session_timeout`.  You'll need server level access, and be able to restart your web server (IE Apache) to do this.

Comment: Ok thanks for your replies I don't have server level access. The link you sent me tells me how to set a cookie and then let the user know how much time has passed with that cookie what I'm asking is when I set a session in PHP how much time is set by default till it expires?

Comment: @user6895584 The lifetime of a session is [configured](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) by `session.gc_probability`, `session.gc_divisor` and `session.gc_maxlifetime`. Read about these settings to determine the average session lifetime (probability is involved).